# c++ cli Сортировка ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli

Есть xml файл, у каждой ноды есть 2 атрибута, допустим `name` и `number`, хочу сделать `ListBox` с сортировкой по одному из атрибутов, для наглядности xml:

```
<xml>
 <node name="al capone" number="3" />
 <node name="hyunday" number="1" />
 <node name="lego" number="2" />
</xml>
```

Я могу сортировать `ListBox` по алфавиту, но мне нужно сортировать его по нажатии кнопки по одному из атрибутов. Хотел сейчас формировать List из этого xml и уже сортировать его, но что-то для C++/CLI примеров маловато, а перевести с C# как-то не получается. Добавлю еще тег C#, так как обычно у меня нету проблем с переводом на CLI, а народу там побольше.

Comment: суть в том чтобы наталкнуть меня на самый простой способ, в этом языке есть несколько способов и как минимум с тремя из них я не знаком, если у кого есть опыт, подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - перейти на C#. Готов поспорить, что кода у вас от силы несколько сотен строк. Переписать их можно за несколько дней максимум, после чего жизнь станет легка и приятна.

Впрочем, после этого вам станут советовать перейти с WinForms на WPF. Потом на .NET Core (кроссплатформенность же!) и т. д.

Также уверен, что это задание по учёбе. Поэтому от C++/CLI никуда не деться. Что ж, поехали!

---

В xml могут быть использованы любые имена элементов за одним исключением: корневой тег не может называться `xml`. Так что придётся переименовать. Например, назовём его `nodes`.

```
<nodes>
 <node name="al capone" number="3" />
 <node name="hyunday" number="1" />
 <node name="lego" number="2" />
</nodes>
```

---

В современной разработке ПО самым правильным подходом считается создание модели для каждой используемой сущности. Поэтому создадим класс `node`:

```
namespace CppWinForm1 {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Xml::Serialization;
    using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

    public ref class node
    {
    public:
        [XmlAttributeAttribute]
        property String^ name;
    public:
        [XmlAttributeAttribute]
        property int number;

    public:
        static int Sort(node^ node1, node^ node2)
        {
            return node1->number.CompareTo(node2->number);
        }
    public:
        static Comparison<node^>^ comparison = gcnew Comparison<node^>(&Sort);
    };

    typedef List<node^>^ NodeList;
}
```

Пространство имён замените на своё.

Обратите внимание: названия класса и свойств совпадают с именами тегов xml. Свойства и класс объявлены `public` - это нужно для того, чтобы десериализатор их мог увидеть.

Также в классе имеется метод `Sort` (думаю, назначение понятно) и `Comparison`, необходимый для передачи в метод сортировки коллекции.

Ещё имеется `typedef`, также необходимый для использования в сериализаторе.

Подключаем этот файл в файле формы с помощью `#include`.

---

В классе формы объявляем поле - это коллекция, в которой будет храниться список наших классов:

```
NodeList nodes; // List<node^>^ nodes;
```

Её можно объявить и как `List<node^>^ nodes;`, но раз уж у нас имеется `typedef`, то почему бы его не использовать.

Создаём ещё одно поле. Это класс, автоматически (де)сериализующий данные в/из xml. Именно для него нужны публичные свойства и совпадения имён.

```
XmlSerializer^ serializer = gcnew XmlSerializer(NodeList::typeid, gcnew XmlRootAttribute(L"nodes"));
```

В конструктор нужно передать тип класса, с которым он будет работать. Написать `List<node^>^::typeid` нельзя. Поэтому и был использован `typedef`.

В том месте, где нужно считать данные из файла xml и поместить их в `ListBox`, пишем следующий код:

```
FileStream^ stream = File::OpenRead(L"in.txt");
nodes = (NodeList)serializer->Deserialize(stream);
stream->Close();

listBox1->ValueMember = L"number";
listBox1->DisplayMember = L"name";
listBox1->DataSource = nodes;
```

Открываем поток. Сериализатор считывает данные и заполлняет коллекцию данными - одна строка кода! Удобно, не правда ли? Закрываем поток.

Потом привязываем коллекцию к листбоксу. Это тоже делается одной строкой! Если ещё не знакомы с привязкой данный - бегом читать [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Осталось сделать сортировку. Всё просто:

```
nodes->Sort(node::comparison);

listBox1->DataSource = nullptr;

listBox1->ValueMember = L"number";
listBox1->DisplayMember = L"name";
listBox1->DataSource = nodes;
```

У коллекции `List` есть метод `Sort`, его и используем. В него передаём наш `comparison`. После чего делаем перепривязку данных.

Используемые пространства имён:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Xml::Serialization;
```

Comment: на выходе в листбокс добавляются не значения атрибута name а вот такое: CppWinForm1.node

Comment: @Smirnov - задайте точное имя свойства в `ListBox->DisplayMember`.

Comment: name куда точнее?

Comment: @Smirnov - должно работать. Просто точно скопируйте код. Ключевое слово `property` указано в классе node?

Comment: вы правы, сейчас создал отдельный проект куда скопировал все без изменений, все работает.

Comment: я понял в чем была поблема, у моего listBox DrawMode по схеме OwnerDrawFixed, если поставить Normal то код работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне использовать ваш код сохранив DrawMode моего листбокса?

Comment: @Smirnov - гм... Наверное, стоит задать новый вопрос. В нём покажи код ручной отрисовки. Нужно знать, откуда берётся значение.

Comment: OwnerDrawFixed задано для того чтобы цвет выделенного элемента изменить со стандартного на свой. Так новый вопрос? Там получится столько кода... Твой код + мой код DrawItem... Кому захочется вникать?

Comment: Все проблему решил, наполняю листбокс без привязки а через цикл for each для каждого итема в листе. А так как сортируется сам лист, а не лист бокс, сложностей нет. Выкрутился)